# How to use Spring Security in a Web API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am creating a Web API using Spring Boot, where I want to use Spring Security for authentication with its Remember-Me functionality. **Note, I am creating a Web API and not a REST API which means I won't be using JWT based authentication rather I'll be using `Cookies` and `Sessions`.**

By default, Spring Security provides a Login and Logout page which I am not using, rather I created an endpoint where I am authenticating user myself using `AuthenticationManager`, but I am not able to use Spring Security's Remember-Me functionality. It seems that Remember-Me is only activated when using their own Login form.

I just want to know if I can use Spring Security as it is in my Web API, with slight modifications (logging in and logging out users myself) with everything else handled by Spring. If not, is there any other workaround or would I have to re-create Remember-me functionality myself?

Comment: If this is a Web API, not a REST API, how are you asking the user for credentials without a login form, and associated `login` handler?

Comment: Using an endpoint, I've created a controller [POST] which takes user credentials via Request Body.

Comment: Which is similar to the built-in `/login` POST handler, that takes the user and password from the Form POST body and performs the login operation, incl. setting up remember-me. So if you need to figure out how the remember-me is done, look at the source code of the built-in POST handler.

Answer (score 0):

[Authentication in SpringBoot]

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ This link contains the basic to complete Authentication and Authorisation details you are looking for.

Work around is, You can simply use OAuth instead of OAuth2. You can extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and add your Authentication logic( Session,Cache or Username/Password based on your Preference).

Yeah, you can also include remember me feature by simple change in your class. Code below

`
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
  http.authorizeRequests().  
  antMatchers("/index", "/user","/").permitAll()  
  .antMatchers("/admin").authenticated()  
  .and()  
  .formLogin()  
  .loginPage("/login")  
  .and()  
  .rememberMe()  
  .key("rem-me-key")  
  .rememberMeParameter("remember") // it is name of checkbox at login page  
  .rememberMeCookieName("rememberlogin") // it is name of the cookie  
  .tokenValiditySeconds(100) // remember for number of seconds  
  .and()  
  .logout()  
  .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
```

}
`
Hope this helps

Comment: But the whole point was that I don't want a login page. I have a login controller which takes user credentials via Request Body. In that parameter I am using `AuthenticationManager` to authenticate the user. I've enabled the `rememberMe()` but it did not work when I authenticated user myself and is only working when using Spring's login page, which I don't want to use.

Comment: The default security in Spring Boot is Basic. You could disable it by setting security.basic.enabled=false.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to overcome the basic security of Spring configuration is to use the filter.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
    {
     security.httpBasic().disable();
    }
}
```

Or you can disable the Spring Security auto-configuration. But it is not recommended though.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```